# JQuery Progress bar animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

Trying to display a progress bar using jquery and javascript, but it is not been displayed.

```js
var show_time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 5000;

setTimeout(function() {
  $("#progress").hide()
}, show_time);

var myCountdown = $('#progress').progressBarTimer({
  autostart: true, // default false
  timeLimit: show_time,
  baseStyle: 'bg-info',
  completeStyle: 'bg-success',
  animated: true,
  striped: true,
  label: {
    show: true,
    type: 'percent'
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="progress"></div>

<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Countdown-Timers-Bootstrap-4-Progressbar/jquery.progressBarTimer.js"></script>
```

It only shows the bar, nothing is happening in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the wrong named property:

```
autostart
```

Rename it into:

```
autoStart
```

Otherwise you have to start the progressbar manually by using `start`:

```
$("#countdown").progressBarTimer({
  timeLimit: 60,
  warningThreshold: 5,
  autoStart: false,
  onFinish  : function () { console.log('completed') }
}).start()
```

Although it should also work by using `outstart` according to the docs on how to setup this progressbar, you can see [here](https://github.com/imalliar/jquery.progressBarTimer#default-options) that this property should be named `autoStart` instead.

And note that there is a `onFinish` callback that can be used to do something after the progress-bar has finished so use this property instead of a standalone `setTimeout` to hide the progressbar afterwards. And `timeLimit` expects a value in seconds not in milliseconds. In order to let your users not wait too long, this operation might be more suitable for you:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 5;
```

This example shows what I mean:

```js
var show_time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 5;

var myCountdown = $('#progress').progressBarTimer({
  autoStart: true, // default false
  timeLimit: show_time,
  baseStyle: 'bg-info',
  completeStyle: 'bg-success',
  animated: true,
  striped: true,
  onFinish  : function () { 
      setTimeout(function() {
          $("#progress").hide()
      }, 1000);
  },
  label: {
    show: true,
    type: 'percent'
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="progress"></div>

<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Countdown-Timers-Bootstrap-4-Progressbar/jquery.progressBarTimer.js"></script>
```

Comment: `show_time` was too big! You should see something when you reduce show_time, let's say 60

Comment: I have provided an example that should fulfil your requirements.